# Que me traiga todos los valores no solo el primero Larvel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo este codigo pero no puedo hacer que me traiga todos los valores que estan en esa transferencia solo me trae el primero.

```
public function updateStatus(Request $request)
    {

        DB::beginTransaction();
         
        try {
            $id = Auth::user()->id;
            $query = DB::table('transfers')
            ->where('id', '=', $request->id)
            ->update([
                'status' => 2,
                'authUser_id' => $id,
                'authDate' => now(),
                'updated_at' => now()
            ]);
            

            $transDetail = TransferDetail::where('transfer_id', $request->id);

            $inventory = $transDetail->first()->inventory_id; 
            
            dd($inventory);
            $transfer = Transfer::find($request->id);
            $idWarehouse = Warehouse::where('id', $transfer->toWarehouse_id)->first()->id;
                        
            $query = DB::table('inventories') 
            ->where('id', '=', $inventory)
            ->update([
                'status_id' => 1,
                'warehouse_id' => $idWarehouse,
                
            ]);

            $this->getTransfer($request->id);

            DB::commit();

            //return $this->index($request);

            return ['type' => 'success', 'msg' => 'Transferencia creada correctamente.'];

        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            // throw $e;
            DB::rollBack();
            return ['type' => 'error', 'msg' => $e];
        }
    }
```

Este es el que quiero modificar pero trae un error al quitarle el first().

```
 $inventory = $transDetail->first()->inventory_id;
```

Transfer uso el id para que la informacion que actualiza es en otra tabla.

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

se une con la tabla TransferDetail para poder mostrar el id del inventory que quiero cambiar.

| transfer_id | inventory_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 5 |

La idea es que al seleccionar la tranfernecia de id = 2 me modifique los inventory de esa transferencia que serian 12 y 13.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que

```
$transDetail = TransferDetail::where('transfer_id', $request->id);
```

devuelve una coleccion de `TransferDetail`.
Si le sacas el `first()`:

```
$inventory = $transDetail->inventory_id;
```

Te lanza un error porque estas intentando acceder al atributo `inventory_id` de una coleccion.

Una opcion que tenes seria usar un `foreach`, algo asi:

```
foreach($transDetail as $detail){
   $inventoryId = $detail->inventory_id;
}
```